# Multi list drop down absolute position over and under one another?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How do I invert one list underneath the other so on dropdown the other list stay underneath in position and not floating at the bottom? How do I make the drop down menu not change positions?

```
<html>
<div id="cat">
<h3>Catagory</h3>
<ul>
<li> <a href="box">design</a></li>
<li><a href="#box2">design</a></li>
    <li><a href="#box2">design</a></li>
<ul>
</div>
<div id="cat2">
<h3> catagory </h3>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#box2">design</a></li>
    <li><a href="#box2">design</a></li>
    <li><a href="#box2">design</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<style type="text/css">
.cat{position:relative;
margin: 10px 10px 10px 19px;
padding: 10px; 
border: 2px solid black; 
width: 200px;
z-index:200;
clear:top;}
.cat > ul { display: none; margin-top:-2px;}
.cat:hover > ul {display: block; background: #f9f9f9; border-top: 1px solid black; height:168px;}
.cat:hover > ul > li { padding: 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #4f4f4f; width:200px; margin-left:-60px; margin-top: 1px;}
.cat:hover > ul > li:hover { background: white;}
.cat:hover > ul > li:hover > a { color: red; }
.cat2{position:absolute;display:block; margin: 10px 10px 10px 19px;
padding: 10px; border: 2px solid black; width: 200px;z-index:100;}

</style>
```

Comment: are you using jquery to change these list into select box?

Comment: Hey, it seems you have some error in your code ;) If you are using ID, then style it by ID (#cat), and not by class (.cat). Also, in the first `<ul>` you forgot the backslash to close the tag.

Comment: Try with css `position:absolute;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have marked `#cat2` with `position:absolute` but you didn't assigned any position. Try adding this line:

```
#cat2 {
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 19px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    z-index:100;
    top:100px; /* --This line --*/
}
```

Is this [Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7q4JD/1/) the expected result?

Comment: */top:100px;/* doesn't solve the problem, two lists one at the top the other underneath, when you hover on top cat it pushes the other cat2 below the list, what I'm trying to do is keep the cat2 nestled underneath cat so its floating on top of the other, there is a div wrapper around the two #box{float:left;
margin: 0 10px 0 20px; 
width:260px; 
height: 230px;
background-color:#FFF;

Comment: @MaeveaMaverick But in the fiddle I posted you, the second list stay  behind the first one when hovering... it isn't what you want?

Comment: yes at 200px; it works. have to adjust width in li. to make it look singular., thank you.